# Find the smallest number in a list and how many times it occurs

Tags: python

So far I have written this much

```
def find_num_min(xlst):

    x = []
    count = 0
    w = 0

   for i in range(len(xlst)):
        if len(xlst) == 0:
              return ()
   else:
        y = sorted(xlst)
        w = y[0]


   return w
```

Comment: @myrotikwarrior Your code still won't do anything

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit; don't change the requirements after you have received answers. (Accept one of the answers here, and) ask a new question with the proper details spelled out completely.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like that, but python has many built in functions that can help you write shorter, more readable code:

```
def find(xlst):

    smallest = min(xlst)
    count = xlst.count(smallest)
    
    print(f"The smallest number is {smallest}, it occurs {count} times.")

    return smallest, count
```

Comment: This gave me an error min() arg is an empty sequence this is most likely because the first list is empty

Comment: we can test for that

Comment: I tested for it and I am still getting the same error

Comment: I think its because of it being a nested list

Comment: Your requirements say nothing about nested lists. Don't move the goalposts; accept one of the answers you got and ask a new question with your *actual* requirements properly spelled out.

Comment: that was my mistake im new to this stuff sorry again

Answer (score 1):

In old boring inefficient longhand, just to show you what this could look like,

```py
def find_num_min(xlst):
    smallest = None
    count = 0
    for elt in xlst:
        if not count or elt < smallest:
            smallest = elt
            count = 1
        elif elt == smallest:
            count += 1
    return smallest, count
```

The condition `if not count` takes care to set `smallest` to something in the first iteration (and prevents us from attempting to compare `elt` to `smallest` when the latter is `None`, which woud cause Python to error out); in every subsequent iteration, `count` will be at least 1. (Go over this with pen and paper on a few simple example lists to make sure this is true.)

But definitely learn to look for existing code before writing your own. Both of the subtasks here are easily - and in many ways, better - done with existing functions from Python's standard library.

Comment: I did it this way but the problem is the first list in the nested list is returning 0,0 whereas it should return an empty parentheses

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about nested lists; all the answers here are written for, and will only work with, plain lists of numbers. Again, accept one of the answers here, and ask a new question if you still need help.

Answer (score 0):

use numpy

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(xlst)
minimum = x.min()
count = (x == minimum).sum()
```

Comment: no need for external libraries when python has builtins that can achieve the same thing.

Comment: @ElectricShadow that's not true because my implementation is vectorized and scales well as it uses `numpy`, whereas native python implementation is only good for teaching purposes. To answer the OP question in the real world you would use `numpy`, not python built in libraries for your task. Your comment is like saying do not use pandas when same thing can be achieved using built in dictionaries :), total nonsense.

Comment: "In the real world" is very vague. In the full stack development world, python builtins are the way to go (for something like this, of course)

Comment: This isn't as fast as you might think it is.  Run timeit on this and the builtin solutions. I think you will be suprised ( I tested on 10**7 elements)

Comment: I the real world means for production code. As I said maybe using python builtins for this is what they teach you at the high school. But it's ok I don't want to dirty the OP with flames any further.

Comment: Production code use a lot of builtins, sure numpy has a lot of uses but it isn't the only way to write production code.

Comment: In production code which doesn't already use Numpy for something else, this should get you fired.

Comment: @ChristianSloper I ran `%%timeit` both in pycharm and jupyterlab (tested on 10**7) with an array of normally distributed random numbers. My implementation takes 33ms on average vs 460ms on average for yours. I agree is not hundreds times faster but still is 13 times faster. I think it is enough to make my point.

Comment: @tripleee I am really sure if you propose a solution which is 13 times faster then the current implementation you will get fired right away. Where I work you got bonuses for that. But maybe where you work rationality is not used for business decisions?

Comment: @ChristianSloperI never said that  numpy is the only way for writing production code.

Comment: In our next episode, a dismayed and puzzled @gioxc86 learns that none of the other fighter pilots take the F-6 to the grocery store.

Comment: @gioxc88 Your speed is only true if you have already converted to np.array, if you include conversion then yours is slower. 493ms vs 261ms.  So you are dependent on using numpy throughout the code. Also as other point out, if your "speedup" is the only thing that needs numpy to be included it probably isn't worth it.

Comment: @ChristianSloper I agree with you but please remember how this all started. A guy saying "no need for external libraries when python has builtins that can achieve the same thing". Well this sentence is very misleading especially for someone who is new to python. Everything can be achieved with builtins python library, you can even rewrite your own implementation of tensorflow with it, But should you do it? I don't think so

Comment: @gioxc88 the guy saying "no need for external libraries when python has builtins that can achieve the same thing" was expecting you to consider the context, in this case, the question. Someone learning the basics maybe needs to learn builtins first. Just saying.

Comment: @tripleee seeing you comparing numpy for counting occurrences of minimum in an array of numbers to a pilot taking the F-6 to go to the grocery store really makes me laugh. If you try to make a search of the most used python libraries, numpy is always on top of that.

Comment: Sure, but if you add 12 megs of complex dependencies to optimize the performance of a trivial function which gets called once, you need to adjust your priorities.

Answer (score 0):

using Counter

```py
from collections import Counter

lst = [2,1,2,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,2,2]
c = Counter(lst)
lowest = min(c.keys())
print(f"lowest key: {lowest}, how many times: {c[lowest]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lambda function:

```py
find_num_min = lambda xlst: (None, 0) if len(xlst) == 0 else (
    (smallest := min(xlst)),
    xlst.count(smallest)
)
```

Here is how a lambda function works, showing the same function in lambda form and normal function form:

```py
# normal function
def func(param1, param2):
    return param1 + param2

# lambda function
func = lambda (param1, param2): param1 + param2
```

Next, there are shortened if statements called ternary operators. These two statements are the same, as an example:

```py
# normal if statements
if num > 0:
    print("positive")
else:
    print("negative")

# ternary
print("positive" if num > 0 else "negative")
```

The `:=` operator is the same as the `=` operator, but it returns the value in addition to setting the value of whatever is on the left. Example:

```py
print(n := 5) # prints 5 while setting n to 5
print(n) # also prints 5, as n was set to 5
```

This is useful because it means we don't have to find the minimum value twice.

Finally, the `min` function is built into Python and can be used to find the minimum value in an list. You can also use the `count` method on a list to find the number of times a value occurs in the list.

Putting all of these pieces together, we arrive at the final, optimized, one-line function at the beginning of this answer.

Comment: Not my downvote, but hardly a suitable answer for a beginner-level question.

Comment: @tripleee I added an explanation of all the features I used. Is this more suitable for a beginner?

Comment: I still havent figured out how to do it because the first nested list is empty hence list index is out of range

Comment: @myrotikwarrior fixed